# Tp Link Wireless adapter doesn't want to transmit deauth packets after a fresh installation of Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, deauth-attack

I have a TP-Link TL-WN727N wireless adapter that works out of the box with Kali Linux (I'm using a VM) which I have been using for quite some time. This card has worked flawlessly ever since I first got into kali.

But suddenly after I updated Kali to a later version, it refuses to specifically send deauth packets. Whenever I use `aireplay-ng`or `wifite`  literally everything else other than that works perfectly.

I've tried rolling back to older versions of Kali and tried sending deauth packets but it still doesn't work. Neither aireplay-ng or wifite return any errors.

But here's the funny part, there have been a few instances that it just somehow works and actually manages to send those packets and then returns to being useless again.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check your drivers

Comment: thanks for your reply schroeder but as i mentioned it works out of the box i didnt have to download any drivers also if i didn't have the right drivers wouldnt the card be unusable? As it is now it can still surf the web and do everything else

Comment: Have you checked the drivers, though?

Comment: Hello @GeneralKenobi and welcome to the community. You can check your drivers/firmware with `lsmod`

Comment: alright i've used `lsmod` to check the drivers but i have no idea what im looking at can i paste the output of the command here?